# Trying to create an Audit Log on Sequelizer

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, sequelize.js

I'm using Universal Hooks but I'm having a problem: I can't find the model name or table name.

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize(database, username, password, {
  host: host,
  dialect: dialect,
  pool: {
    max: pool.max,
    min: pool.min,
    acquire: pool.acquire,
    idle: pool.idle,
  },
  logging: (msg) => logger.debug(msg),
  define: {
    hooks: {
      afterCreate(instance, options) {
        console.log(instance);
      }
    }
  }
});
```

In the console log I get this:

```
superRoles {
  dataValues: {
    id: 1,
    nombre: 'SUPERUSUARIO',
    permisos: '{}',
    updatedAt: 2020-11-04T06:36:11.352Z,
    createdAt: 2020-11-04T06:36:11.352Z
  },
  _previousDataValues: { nombre: undefined, permisos: undefined, id: null },
  _changed: Set { 'nombre', 'permisos', 'id' },
  _options: {
    isNewRecord: true,
    _schema: null,
    _schemaDelimiter: '',
    attributes: undefined,
    include: undefined,
    raw: undefined,
    silent: undefined
  },
  isNewRecord: false
}
```

How do I get the model or the **superRoles** value?

Comment: Did you try to look at `options` ?

Comment: Yes 
`{
  hooks: true,
  validate: true,
  fields: [ 'id', 'nombre', 'permisos', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt' ],
  defaultFields: [ 'id', 'nombre', 'permisos', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt' ],
  returning: true
}`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12486

I use:

```
instance.constructor.options
```